# ¿porque no me sale todo lo que ingrese java?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

       String nombre=null;

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            nombre=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese un elemento");

        }
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,nombre);

    }

}
```

después de ejecutar este ciclo solo me aparece el ultimo dato que ingrese los demás no me aparecen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te explico tu código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

       String nombre=null;//Creas la variable nombre nula

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            nombre=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese un elemento");
            //nombre toma lo que capta con el JOptionPane.showInputDialog()
        }
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,nombre); // muestra el nombre

    }

}
```

Lo que pasa en este caso en que cada vez que el ciclo `for`, hace su recorrido, la variable `nombre`, obtiene un valor diferente y el anterior se elimina, es decir:

A la primera iteración del bucle `for`, si ingresas el nombre "Juan", la variable nombre obtendrá ese valor, pero a la segunda iteración, al ingresar otro nombre, por ejemplo "María", en valor de "Juan", cambia por el de "María"

Es por eso que al momento de terminar el bucle, muestra el último valor que mandaste.

---

En el caso de querer guardar todos los datos que obtuviste, se debe de crear un arreglo de tipo `String`:

```
String[] nombres = new String[4];
```

- `String[]` =  indica que es de tipo arreglo `String`
- `nombres` = es el nombre de la variable de tipo `Array String`
- `String[4]` = el 4, indica el tamaño del `Array`

Se utiliza dentro del bucle `for`

```
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            nombres[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese un elemento");
        }
```

Comment: entiendo muchas gracias, entonces tu sabrias como puedo hacer  para que el anterior no se borre sino que se almacene y al final muestre todos los datos que había puesto

Comment: Edito mi respuesta en un minuto para mostrarte una posible opción :)

Comment: oh entiendo muchas gracias

Comment: Lo he cambiado, espero que te ayudara :)

Comment: si   me sirvio mucho, gracias